# nodeAffinity with preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution set always schedules a pod on an incorrect node

Tags: kubernetes

I have two worker nodes in my environment. I have added a label to one of them like so:

`kubectl label nodes "${node}" type=infrastructure --overwrite`

In my service yaml file, I have set the following up:

```
    affinity:
      nodeAffinity:
        preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - weight: 1
          preference:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: "type"
              operator: In
              values: ["infrastructure"]
```

The `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` rule should mean that the kubernetes scheduler should try its best to deploy the pods to the node with the "infrastructure" label, but if it is unable to (e.g. not enough resources), it will deploy to a different node in the cluster.

I am seeing that every time I deploy the service (3 pods), that 1 pod always gets deployed to the node without the label.

Is there any way to find out why the kubernetes scheduler chose the unlabelled node? If it was a resource issue, I would expect to see it logged in the events, but instead I see the scheduler choose the unlabeled node straight away:

```
    Normal  Scheduled              23m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned es-master-5f55dd9dd-2n48b to pink02
```

I understand that I can use the rule `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` to force the pods onto the labeled node, but I don't want to do this because some environments may not have the label.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you actually do not have enough resources since the nodeAffinity is a pretty simple process as it is score-based. 
[Comment in the github doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/bbf5625630d59b36147a6a8c4be2c134c47ae8b2/pkg/scheduler/algorithm/priorities/node_affinity.go)

> / CalculateNodeAffinityPriorityMap prioritizes nodes according to node
>   affinity scheduling preferences   // indicated in
>   PreferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution. Each time a node
>   match a preferredSchedulingTerm,   // it will a get an add of
>   preferredSchedulingTerm.Weight. Thus, the more
>   preferredSchedulingTerms   // the node satisfies and the more the
>   preferredSchedulingTerm that is satisfied weights, the higher   //
>   score the node gets.

[Another:](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/scheduling/nodeaffinity.md)

> - a field called  `RequiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`  which is identical to 
>     `RequiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution`  except that the
>     system may or may not try to eventually evict the pod from its node.

Please try to check if you really have enough resources as according to the quoted documentation the behavior seems to be applicable to the better scoring of the second node after putting first pods into the 1st node. 
Answering your last question: you will not see this in the event logs as those kinds of events are not logged, theoretically you should see them in debug mode, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: I have been looking into the resources here. I gathered system resources at the time the scheduler selected the nodes to deploy on. There is 70% available cpu and 20GB ram free. 
However when I checked resources a little later (after all pods have come up), I can see a spike on the labelled node where CPU hit 85%. This spike is after the pods have already been scheduled, but during the pod startup sequence.  Is Kubernetes clever enough to know when scheduling that this spike is going to occur? Is this why its selecting a different node in advance?

Comment: PS: Something I have noticed is that the pod that always goes to the incorrect node is ALWAYS initialized first, so I don't think you can say "the behavior seems to be applicable to the better scoring of the second node after putting first pods into the 1st node".

Comment: Kubernetes will check only for the limits and requests which you set in the pod spec, not the real resource usage in the scheduling phase.
Try changing the affinity from proffered to required for test purposes - is the Kubernetes spawning all the pods? If not what kind of event is generated for "unspawned" pod. What about additional node selectors, node tolerance settings etc. ? Do you have those?

Comment: Using requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution I get this error:

Error: release elasticsearch failed: Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1beta1.Deployment.Spec: v1beta1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Affinity: v1.Affinity.NodeAffinity: v1.NodeAffinity.RequiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found [, error found in #10 byte of ...|ecution":[{"preferen|..., bigger context ...|"requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution":[{"preference":{"matchExpressions":[{"key":"type","|...

Comment: Actually forget the previous comment. I had to update the yaml for proper syntax for "required". So with "required" set, nodeAffinity is working fine.
So why with "preferred" do the pods not go to the correct nod?. I have the following tolerations set:
`tolerations:
      - key: dedicated
        operator: Equal
        value: infrastructure
        effect: NoSchedule
`

Comment: Can you share full yaml file with all toleration and affinity rules? Also please attach the list of labels on pods.

Comment: I worked around this issue by adding a value to a values.yaml that can be set by the user during a helm install if they want to use "required" or "preferred", depending on their env